# Inject Interface to Overloaded Class Constructor Using StructureMap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, structuremap

I'm using **StructureMap** in **ASP .Net MVC 4** and I have got the following Interface and implemented class in my project infrastructure :

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Commit();
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public void Commit()
    {
        // Track all changes in database
    }
}
```

My `HomeController` is used the IUnitOfWork interface as constructor parameter :

```
public class HomeController
{
    IUnitOfwork unitOfWork;

    public HomeController(IUnitOfwork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
 }
```

How can I inject `IUniOfWork` interface to overloaded `HomeController` class as parameter?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read [the quick start](http://docs.structuremap.net/QuickStart.htm)?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is too vague.

Comment: @Mironline, I am edited the question with appropriated quality after was closed. I flagged it to reopen by moderators and then response to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must perform the following steps:

1. Remove and uninstall any configurations and packages for StructureMap.
2. Install [structurmap.mvc4 from nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/StructureMap.MVC4)
3. Configure your IoC container as :

   `x.For(IUnitOfWork).Use(UnitOfWork)`